# Differentiate Perfect Tenses of Verbs

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-perfect, future-perfect

Could anyone please differentiate the Present Perfect, Present Past, and Present Future tense of verbs. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "system" of names for English verb constructions is in many respects misleading (if not downright absurd), but no English verb construction  bears such an inherently contradictory name as "Present Past" or "Present Future".

Here are the standard names for the *finite* English constructions, the ones which can be used as independent predications. I use *drive* so you can readily discern the difference between the 'past' form and the past participle, and I ignore inflections for person and number:

[image]

For the complete name of a construction, put the name of the column in which it appears in front of the name of the row in which it appears—for instance, "I have been driving" is *Present Perfect Progressive*.

What traditional grammar calls the "Future" constructions are modal constructions which employ the modal *will*. Modals (except *must*) may be cast in either "present" or "past" form: *can/could*, *may/might*, *shall/should*, *will/would*. These may be named by employing "Modal Present" or "Modal Past" in front of the row name—for instance, "I would have been driven" is a *Modal Past Perfect Passive*.

There are also *nonfinite* constructions: the infinitive and the "present" and "past" participles, and constructions introduced by casting the first auxiliary in these forms:

[image]

There are no "Participial Progressive" constructions and no constructions introduced by past participles of the auxiliaries *have* and *be*; it is difficult to conceive what additional meanings these might express. And there are no nonfinite constructions at all with modals; modal verbs have no nonfinite forms, and the meanings these might express (and do express in other languages) must be expressed in English with "periphrastic modals" such as *be able to*, *be possible to*, *be obliged to*, *have to*, *be going to*.

- **Be warned that none of these names can be relied on as a description of a construction's meaning.**